# How to capitalise first letter of string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have created one form. In that form there are 10 textbox and one button. I would like that when the user enters text into textbox and loses focus, the first letter of the string should be capitalised. So I think javascript is best option for this. Onblur event of all 10 textbox I have to call it. I don't want to call it onbuttonclick event.

// javascript function

```
function capitaliseFirstLetter(string)
{
return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

// cs file

```
page_load()
{
string s1 = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
TextBox1.Attributes.Add("Onblur",capitaliseFirstLetter('"+s1+"'))
}
```

But s1 is always empty because I've called the function in pageload(). How can I handle it?

Comment: this code TextBox1.Attributes.Add("Onblur",capitaliseFirstLetter('"+s1+"')) does not throw exception?!

Comment: It won't throw exception @user2675751. It won't compile in the first place.

Comment: You can use `text-transform: capitalize;` css property. if you want to..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this...

```
page_load()
{
    TextBox1.Attributes.Add("onblur", "capitaliseFirstLetter('" + TextBox1.ClientID + "')");
}
```

Modify your JavaScript function as below...

```
function capitaliseFirstLetter(txtID) {
    var txtString = document.getElementById(txtID).value;
    document.getElementById(txtID).value = txtString.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txtString.slice(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Devraj for ur help.It is working fine with me.Just minute change is instead of getElementByID,used getElementById.

Comment: Sadly there are big implications if your user lives in Turkey... On the server i -> I, on his client computer i -> İ (see the dot). It's called the [4 turkish i problem](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/07/05/turkish-i-problem-and-why-you-should-care.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can declare this `onblur` event on aspx page like below.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onblur="capitaliseFirstLetter(this)">
</asp:TextBox>
```

Then the `javaScript` will be like below.

```
<script language="javascript">
     function capitaliseFirstLetter(textBox)
     {
         return textBox.value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
     } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

very simple answer with variables with two lines

capitalised string is only for first letter, rest will remain lower case

```
var sentence = "string of worlds"
var capitizedString = (sentence.slice(0,1)).toUpperCase() + (sentence.slice(1)).toLowerCase();
```